# Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, use-context

I'm getting the error "Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null" when I use useContext() hook from react in Next.js.

```
// Other imports
import CurrentUserContext from "../../contexts/current-user/current-user.context";

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,
    };
  }

  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    // Auth code
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // unsubscribe code
  }

  render() {
    const { children, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>{title}</title>
        </Head>
        <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={this.state.currentUser}>
          <Header />
        </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Here is where the error happens

```
// Other imports
import CurrentUserContext from "../../contexts/current-user/current-user.context";
import { useContext } from "react";

const Header = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(CurrentUserContext);
  return (
    // Header Jsx
  );
};

export default Header;
```

This is how I created the context file

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const CurrentUserContext = createContext(undefined);

export default CurrentUserContext;
```

Error screenshot below
[image: Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of your context is just `null` and there's no key `currentUser` in your context.

```
this.state = {
  currentUser: null,
};

<CurrentUserContext.Provider value={this.state.currentUser}> // just null
```

To be able to destructure a `currentUser` in your context, you could do:

```
<CurrentUserContext.Provider
  value={{
    currentUser: this.state.currentUser
  }}
>
```

Comment: Also this link make sure context is wrapping in correct location https://ankurraina.medium.com/reactjs-pass-functions-through-context-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-of-450a8edd55b6

Answer (score 1):

Your context value isn't an object to destructure, it's simply a value (currently null), i.e. the context value is simply the value of `this.state.currentUser`, not `{currentUser: this.state.currentUser }`. You can just access it directly, no destructuring necessary.

```
// Other imports
import CurrentUserContext from "../../contexts/current-user/current-user.context";
import { useContext } from "react";

const Header = () => {
  const currentUser = useContext(CurrentUserContext); // <-- Remove the curly brackets
  return (
    // Header Jsx
  );
};

export default Header;
```